# How do I create a pointer to key/value pair of a map in C++?

Tags: c++, dictionary, pointers

I'm trying to explore the different ways of creating pointers. In the following code, I'm trying to create a pointer pointing to a key/value pair of a map in two different ways:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<map>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    //creating the map & the key/value pair
    map<string,string> mp;
    mp["key"]="value";

    //This gives an error:taking the address of a temporary object?
    map<string,string>* pt = &(mp.begin());


    //This, however, works perfectly fine.
    auto it = mp.begin();

    cout<<it->first<<endl<<it->second;//testing

}
```

I don't understand why the first attempt spits out an error, and the second one works fine. Can someone please explain?

Comment: The second does not create a pointer. `mp.begin()` is an iterator, not an internal pair in the map or a pointer to one.

Comment: "key/value pair". It's true that a `std::map` _conceptually_ holds such a pair, and it's true that `std::map<Key, Value::value_type>` is a `std::pair<const Key, Value>`. But that does not mean the actual implementation holds an actual `std::pair` internally, as a C++ object.

Comment: `map<string,string>* ` is a pointer to a **map**, not a pointer to a map's **entry** (value_type).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`mp.begin()` does not return a pointer, it returns an iterator, which is an object that represents a reference to an entry, but still an object in of itself.

You can convert an iterator into a pointer by using `&*iterator`, which means "The address of (`&`) the object referred to (`*`) by that iterator".

Next up, `map<string,string>*` is a pointer to the map itself. If you want a pointer to an entry within the map, you need to use `map<string, string>::value_type*`.

Putting all that together, what you want is:

```
map<string, string>::value_type* pt = &*mp.begin();
```

Comment: At which point you might be better of writing `auto pt = &*...`.

Comment: From the first sentence of your answer, I realized that I don't fully know the difference between a pointer and an iterator. What exactly do you mean by "an object that represents a reference to an entry"?

Comment: @spiritedExit0 It's "something" that acts LIKE a pointer, but is not one. Look at  `std::list`, I can write `for(auto ite = someList.begin(), ite != someList.end(), ite++) {}`. This "feels" like a pointer, but it's walking through a linked list, so clearly it can't be a pointer.